# Matrix expression simplification (linear regression)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

$$
  \left\lVert Y - X\beta \right
\rVert^2 = (Y - X\beta)^T(Y - X\beta) 
$$
$$
  = Y^TY - \beta^TX^TY - Y^TX\beta + \beta^TX^TX\beta
$$
$$
  = \left\lVert Y \right\rVert^2 - 2Y^TX\beta + \left\lVert X\beta \right\rVert^2
$$

I don't understand any of the three simplification steps here.

1. In the first equation, how is this simplification done? Is this a known property?
2. It seems like $(Y - X\beta)^T(Y - X\beta) = (Y^T - X^T\beta^T)(Y - X\beta)$, but not quite since the last term is $\beta^TX^TX\beta$, not $X^T\beta^TX\beta$ -- how is this step done?
3. Is $\left\lVert X\beta \right\rVert^2 = \beta^TX^TX\beta$ a known property? How does $- \beta^TX^TY - Y^TX\beta = - 2Y^TX\beta$ ?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't know anything about matrix algebra, eh? All steps are elementary properties of matrix algebra. Check any 1st year college math book.

Comment: $\|x^2\| = x^\intercal x$ follows immediately of the definitions. Note that $(X\beta)^\intercal = \beta^\intercal X^\intercal.$ Also, $y^\intercal X \beta$ is a real number so it coincides with its transpose. Again, these properties are so basic you may be better off reading any matrix algebra for 1st year college students (this properties should appear in the first 1-2 pages).

Comment: 1. Definition of the dot product on $\mathbb R^n$ ($\lVert x\rVert^2=\langle x,x\rangle = x^\top x$). 2. Check: $(AB)^\top = B^\top A^\top$. 3. $y^\top X \beta\in\mathbb R$ so $y^\top X\beta = (y^\top X\beta)^\top=\beta^\top X y$. I agree with @William that these properties are very basic. But everyone sees everything for the first time at some point, so I wouldn't blame you for not understanding this from the start .

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch and WilliamM. your comments were extremely helpful, thank you so much!